# Categorical neural networks model not running: expected dense_84 to have shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I have data with about 3600 rows and 27 columns. In one of these columns is a label from 1 to 10 which I want to predict from the rest.

Model from scratch:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
import keras
import pandas
import sklearn
import matplotlib

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

dataset = df.values

X = dataset[:,0:27]

Y = dataset[:, 8] ///I want column 8 to be my label column

from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test = train_test_split(X_scale, Y, test_size=0.3)
X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size=0.5)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential([    
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(27,)),    
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),    
    Dense(1, activation='softmax'),])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',              
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',              
              metrics=['accuracy'])


Ytest = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train,)
print('The one hot label is:', Y_train[5])

hist = model.fit(X_train, Ytest,
                 batch_size=32, epochs=20,          
                 validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_84 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (11,)
```

I'm at a complete loss at what's wrong here. Could use a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: what's `y_train.shape`?

Comment: It is (2595,)..

Comment: are you sure? I would think it's 10 or 11 based on your  second sentence. Either way, your last dense layer must have the same number of nodes as `y_train.shape[1]`

Comment: Yes: https://prnt.sc/r0cu2a

I took the entire column so it's 3700 observations (or 2595 in the training set) and 1 column. Is that wrong?

Comment: Maybe you mean Ytest? It is (2595,11). I realize it's confusing, I have both train and test in the model, I mixed the names up when converting to one-hot but it should still run AFAIK.

Comment: Y_train and Y_test should have the same shape is axis 1. In your case `y_train.shape = 2595, 11` and `y_test.shape=(1105, 11)`

Comment: Here are all shapes: https://prnt.sc/r0cwgf

The Ytest variable is just a one-hot of Y_train. Do these shapes look off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207545/discussion-between-kenan-and-user3078100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1 - 
It looks like you forgot to one hot encode your `Y_train`, the error states your last layer is expecting a tensor of shape [batch_size, 11].

or

2 - 
Your last Dense layer should have 11 nodes not 1